# android set shared preferences from an xml file crashes

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to set shared_prefs from an xml file but, when simulating, app crashes returning a lot of error messages starting from: FATAL EXCEPTION: main.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //first boot
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.prefs, false);
```

errors:

```
03-02 16:57:39.508: W/dalvikvm(15516): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-02 16:57:39.528: E/AndroidRuntime(15516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 16:57:39.528: E/AndroidRuntime(15516): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testXml.com/com.testXml.com.PreferencesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class map
```

and many more.

prefs.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>

<map>
<string name="test">test</string>
</map>
```

Comment: Please post the complete logcat of the exception thrown.

Comment: what editor does? post your layout and full code and see your layout (Binary XML file line #2).

Comment: @Jaume, Are you sure this is the complete logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<map>` is not a valid tag for `preferences.xml`.

See an example [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/xml/preferences.html).